# Questions about solutions to $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to answer the following questions:

> 1. Let $A$ be an arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix and let $Ax=b$ have more than two solutions. Does it follow that $Ax=b$ is solvable for every $b$?
> 2. Does there exist a real matrix $A$ such that $Ax=0$ has exactly two solutions?
> 3. Does there exist a real matrix $A$ such that $Ax=0$ has exactly one solution but $Ax=b$ (for $b \not=0$) has more than one solution?

Usually I post my attempt but I have no clue how to start. Can someone give me hint?

More importantly, how do I approach these questions? I have thought about "trial and error" but that seems to be a pretty terrible idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If you have the rank-nullility theorem that will help greatly, along with observations such as if $Ax_1 = Ax_2 = b$ where $x_1 \neq x_2$ then $Ax = 0$ will have a non-zero solution $x = x_1 - x_2$.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some hints.

1. Use that $n=\dim(\ker(A))+\dim(\mathrm{im}(A))$, a.k.a. the rank-nullity theorem.
2. Use that $\ker(A)$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.
3. Use that $\ker(A)=\{0\}\implies A\text{ injective}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't really get the rank-nullity theorem and it keeps coming up so I think this is a good time to sit down and properly study it. I am not sure how 2 and 3 help me. Maybe i just need to think about it a bit. Can I comment on your post again in case I don't get anywhere?

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: I am not getting anywhere :/. I don't even see the point of the rank-nullity theorem (problably because I don't get it). I can't even understand the answer if I look up the solution: http://www.math.ku.edu/~slshao/fall2013math290lecture8.pdf
Could you maybe give me dumbed down explanation of why the rank-nullity theorem helps me here.