# Proof: If $Ax=b$ has more than one solution, it has infinitely many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a follow up question to a question I asked yesterday: [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339036/questions-about-solutions-to-ax-b)

I want to prove the following statement:

> Let $A$ be an arbitrary $n \times n$ matrix, and let $Ax=0$ have more
>   than one solution then it follows that $Ax=b$ van be solved for every
>   $b$

I didn't know how to do it so I looked up the answer and tried to understand the proof from there: [Link](http://www.math.ku.edu/~slshao/fall2013math290lecture8.pdf)

The beginning is pretty straigh forward:

Let $u$ and $v$ be two different solutions

$$\implies Au=0 , Av=0 \implies Au=Av \iff A(u-v)=0$$

since $u \not=v$ it follows that $u-v$ is not the zero solution. So far so good. However I don't understand this next step:

For $k \in \Bbb N, u+k(u-v)$ is a solution to $Ax=b$

$$A(u+k(u-v))=Au+Ak(u-v)=\color{blue}{x+0}=\color{blue}{x}$$

First, why does  $k \space \space \text{have to be} \in \Bbb N$ Why can't $\space  k \in \Bbb R$? Second, how is author getting the answer I marked in blue. How does getting $\color{blue}{x}$ tell me anything about the number of solutions?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want to show that $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions? Do you want to show that $Ax=b$ has a solution for every $b$? Both? Neither?

Comment: The author didn't say it had to be $k\in \mathbb N$. but restricting to the natural numbers is enough to prove the goal, so why not?. The author proved that the set of solutions contains the set $\{A(u+k(u-v))\colon k\in \mathbb N\}$. This set is infinite, prove it.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval I want to show that IF $Ax=0$ has more than one solution it follows that $Ax=b$ has a solution for every b.

Comment: You can't prove that because it's not true.

Comment: @GitGud Okay that makes sense.

Comment: @TonyK I think I understand my confusion now. The notes I linked prove something entirely different than what I am supposed to prove. However, I don't know how to start to disprove the statement either. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: @SuH In the real numbers, can the equation $ax=b$ be solved for every real numbers $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Try $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ for a concrete example: $A\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\y\end{bmatrix}$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: @GitGud I don't think so. Only if $b$ is in the column space of $a$

Comment: The $x$ in blue should be $b$.

Comment: @Michael Yeah that makes much more sense.

Comment: @TonyK But this does CAN be solved for every $x$ and $y$ or am I missing something here?

Comment: $Ax=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ has no solutions.

Comment: I am very confused now. Didn't you just give the example $$\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}0\\y\end{pmatrix} $$ which I think is solvable for every $x,y$. Now you give the example $$Ax=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} $$.
Isn't this example entirely different than the first one or am I just super terrible at linear algebra?

Also, how does the second example $Ax=(1,0)^T$ satisfy the condition:

$$Ax=0 \space \text{has more than one solution}$$

As far as I can see. $Ax$ is never $0$ in that example.

Comment: @TonyK I hope my questions makes sense. This is all very confusing for me so my questions will problably also be confusing.

Comment: This is not correct. In fact, try to prove this instead: If A is an n by n matrix and $Ax=b$ has more than one solution, then there exists $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax=b$ has no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement underlined in skin-tone is **blatantly false**. If $Ax=0$ has more than one solution, which implies: at least one  solution $k\ne0$, then ${\rm dim\>ker}(A)\geq1$. Therefore $V:={\rm im}(A)$ has dimension $$\dim (V)=n-\dim\ker(A)<n\ .$$ It follows that ${\mathbb R}^n\setminus V$ contains infinitely many vectors $b$, and for all these $b$ the system $Ax=b$ has no solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I "solved" it yesterday by trial and error. I just assumed $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}\implies Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions but not a solution for every $b$. Your way is much better though since it is more general and you don't have to do any guesswork.